# How to detect if browser support specified css pseudo-class?

Tags: javascript, css, detection, pseudo-class, browser-feature-detection

What's concept of detecting support of any css pseudo-class in browser through JavaScript? Exactly, I want to check if user's browser supports `:checked` pseudo-class or not, because I've made some CSS-popups with checkboxes and needs to do fallbacks for old browsers.

**ANSWER:** I'm found already implemented [method](https://gist.github.com/441842) of testing css selectors in a Modernizr ["Additional Tests"](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki).

Comment: [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) detects many things like that.

Comment: I know about Modernizr, but it's don't have tests for css3 pseudo-classes support, only pseudo-elements like `::before`, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply check if your style with pseudo-class was applied.

Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/qPmT2/1/

Comment: Found already implemented [method](https://gist.github.com/441842) of testing css selectors in a Modernizr ["Additional Tests"](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki). Oh, god, why it's not in the core?

Comment: Working solution, but a bit ugly

Answer (score 4):

For anyone still looking for a quick solution to this problem, I cribbed together something based on a few of the other answers in this thread. My goal was to make it succinct.

```
function supportsSelector (selector) {
  const style = document.createElement('style')
  document.head.appendChild(style)
  try {
    style.sheet.insertRule(selector + '{}', 0)
  } catch (e) {
    return false
  } finally {
    document.head.removeChild(style)
  }
  return true
}

supportsSelector(':hover') // true
supportsSelector(':fake') // false
```

Answer (score 3):

[stylesheet.insertRule(rule, index)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule) method will throw error if the rule is invalid. so we can use it.

```
var support_pseudo = function (){
    var ss = document.styleSheets[0];
    if(!ss){
        var el = document.createElement('style');
        document.head.appendChild(el);
        ss = document.styleSheets[0];
        document.head.removeChild(el);
    }
    return function (pseudo_class){
        try{
            if(!(/^:/).test(pseudo_class)){
                pseudo_class = ':'+pseudo_class;
            }
            ss.insertRule('html'+pseudo_class+'{}',0);
            ss.deleteRule(0);
            return true;
        }catch(e){
            return false;
        }
    };
}();


//test
support_pseudo(':hover'); //true
support_pseudo(':before'); //true
support_pseudo(':hello'); //false
support_pseudo(':world'); //false
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're OK with using Javascript, you might skip the detection and go right for the shim: [Selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/)

Comment: It will be better do not use Selectivizr, because perfomance is dicreasing due to parse CSS before rendering page.