# How to detect browser support for :after and :before

Tags: javascript, css

I am building menus that rely on the css `:after` and `:before` pseudo selectors. How can I detect if the browser supports them?

I found [this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-detect-css-support-in-browsers-with-javascript/) that explains how to detect css properties that can be accessed in JavaScript, but it doesn't seem to apply to my case.

[Edit] In answer to the comments and first replies:

- The pseudo-selectors add elements, for example arrows for breadcrumb navigation.
- I prefer feature detection to browser detection, because some browsers will work in quirks mode (typically IE 8 / IE 9)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you want to do this?

Comment: And what does “rely” mean in this case? What would be missing or even broken in your menu if they were not supported?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect if browser support specified css pseudo-class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8531940/how-to-detect-if-browser-support-specified-css-pseudo-class)

Comment: @isherwood `::before` and `::after` are not pseudo classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.querySelector(':after, :before');
```

Comment: I like that! Let me do some testing. Why body btw? Based on the other answers, I am actually thinking that document.querySelector could be enough.

Comment: It doesn't have to be body, just document will do.

Comment: Minor comment: you actually need to do it in 2 steps (document.querySelector)&&(document.querySelector(':after, :before'))

Answer (score 2):

Well, they're supported in every browser other than IE 7 and under, so this should do.

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
  <script> window.contentSupported = false; </script>
<![endif]-->
```

and in your javascript you can do.

```
if(window.contentSupported !== false) {
   // :before is supported
} else {
   // :before isn't supported
}
```

Comment: I have updated my question, I also need to detect quirks mode.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see here http://caniuse.com/#search=after, :after and :before selectors are supported by every browsers except earlier version of IE8. You could check by a script or conditional comment if the browser is IE and if the version is earlier than version 8.

http://modernizr.com/download/ This is a really good tool to detect which features a browser is able to understand. It's a library, that adds a css class to your html body tag. In your case you have just to check the option for "Css generated content :before and :after".

Comment: I have updated my question, I also need to detect quirks mode.

Comment: Why, are you deliberately going into quirks mode?